# How to remove the first line in a csv file containing paragraphed text in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to delete the first line in a csv file containing paragraphed text in Python.

I have the following python code:

```
# Read the data
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    data = f.read().split("\n")

# Remove the 1st line
del data[0]

# Save the data
with open("file.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(data))
```

The code above can only delete the first line that contains text or characters only. Can't delete cells that contain text that has paragraphs.

Comment: Paragraphs, as in blocks of text? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Indeed: please include a sample of the "paragraphed" text, and your desired output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the paragraph text I mean. Please check this link > https://ibb.co/7yw9Hk9

I want to delete the first row only.

When I run the code above, the result is like this link > https://ibb.co/CvbPSQc

Comment: Open the CSV file in a text editor and look how the line breaks are escaped in multi-line cells. Then you should come up with a way to do the same in your program. Remember that Python sees the file as purely plain text and doesn’t really know how Excel divides the data into rows and cells.

Comment: You’re splitting rows by newline, and removing the first. If the so-called paragraph is a text block containing multiple newlines, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I hope all the content in the first row can be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the CSV as DataFrame and then remove first row and save it again.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(LOAD_FILE_PATH, header=None)[1:]
df.to_csv(SAVE_FILE_PATH, header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanxs @Rahul Vishwakarma .. This code work for me ....